# Python SQLite Return Value

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to return a numeric value from this statement:

```
c = db.execute("""SELECT *, rowid FROM members WHERE barcode = '%s' AND debit > 0 LIMIT 50""" % (s,))
```

But I get this as the returned value:

```
sqlite3.Cursor object at 0xb6cb2720
```

What should I do with this cursor object to get the results?

Comment: Have you tried enumerating `c`?  `for row in c: ...`

Comment: `To retrieve data after executing a SELECT statement, you can either treat the cursor as an iterator, call the cursor’s fetchone() method to retrieve a single matching row, or call fetchall() to get a list of the matching rows.`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
for row in c:
    print row['rowid']
```

Comment: Directly enumerating `c` instead of `c.fetchall()` will require less memory since the entire result set isn't loaded into memory all at once, rather each row would be loaded in one at a time and discarded before the next.

Comment: Updated.  Thanks for the tip.  This is why I love answering questions on SO. My way of thinking is validated or not and either way, I learn something.

Comment: @cdhowie actually SQLite will not necessarily return the entire result set, but it certainly buffers some in memory before returning the next set from a transactional log on disk (unless it's an in-mem DB)... But yes, still certainly more efficient than `list`'ing or `.fetchall`'ing the results.

Comment: @JonClements Of course.  Buffering is good for performance.  But the DB engine knows how much it should buffer to perform better; pulling the entire set into memory is likely to be much worse.

Comment: @cdhowie the slight trade off being that if it's "not that large" - than requesting the whole lot is often more efficient (doesn't require transactional locks and logs for so long) than requesting chunks... but I'm going off-topic here :)

Comment: Indeed. The point is that if you don't know, iterating the cursor is usually the right choice.  *Sometimes* fetching everything is faster (depending on how long it takes you to process it) but that is the exception, not the rule.

Comment: I guess I've done this a bit backwards - I'm wanting to know if "debit" is greater than zero upon inputting a "barcode" by SELECTing the record in the database, and querying if what debit it. The "for row in c:" gave me the error that it must be an integer, so obviously I'm selecting the wrong piece of information here.

Comment: This is my response from the command line:

`sqlite> SELECT *, rowid FROM "members" WHERE "barcode" = '2' AND "debit" > '0' LIMIT 50;
sqlite> SELECT *, rowid FROM "members" WHERE "barcode" = '8897000420' AND "debit" > '0' LIMIT 50;
Ellis Cxxxxx|DD|PUCLxxxxxxx|100|14.95|Aug 04|14.95|8897000420|1`

I need that to say "true" or "false."

Answer (score 0):

One of my problems was, I was using the wrong SQL query to get the data I wanted. See:

```
c = db.execute("""SELECT "debit" FROM "members" WHERE "barcode" = '%s' LIMIT 1""" % (s,))
```

I would then get the response:

```
(0,)
```

Which was what I needed. Now to actually work out how to compare it - I need to say "if c is not equal to (0,) then print 'cross' else print 'tick'..."

Answer (score 0):

try this>>`print(cursorObject.fetchone()[0])`

Answer (score 0):

I just convert to list of tuples

```
sql="SELECT *, rowid FROM members WHERE barcode = '%s' AND debit > 0 LIMIT 50" % (s,)
c = list(db.execute(sql)
```